# Preventing JQuery default behavior in Angular 11 app

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a angular 11.2.4 application in which I have to use a bootstrap (4.6.0) and JQuery based theme. For displaying navbar in mobile view, there is a code using `navbar-collapse`.

```html
<nav class="main-menu navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <!-- Toggle Button -->
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse clearfix" id="navbarsupportedcontent">
    <ul class="navigation clearfix">
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">services</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">service one</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">service two</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In this code, clicking the list element will cause the page to reload and route to the url associated. Instead of refreshing the page, I want to implement a SPA approach and route to instead. I have tried AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked but it is not working.

```html
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  $('li a').on('click', ($event: any) => {
    $event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

I am using bootstrap from `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap: v9.0.2` and external scripts in following order:

```
 "scripts": [
  "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "src/app/shared/scripts/vendor/popper.min.js",
  "jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js",
  "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
  "wowjs/dist/wow.min.js"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need jQuery here. `ng-bootstrap` is an Angular port of `bootstrap`. Angular itself and ng-bootstrap together have enough capabilities. Using jQuery would in this ecosystem only lead to conflicts between frameworks and headaches.

upd:
I see you can not avoid using jQuery. Maybe stop propagation would help:

```js
$event.stopPropagation();
```

Alternatively, I would try to explore the jQuery navbar source code to find out how does it attach the event handler. It might provide an idea on how to disable those handlers.

Comment: Brother I tried to convey this to my client but he is insisting that we use that specific theme (written for a wordpress). I am unable to emulate specific behaviors using angular `nativeElement`.

Comment: %) that's a pity. I hope that misery would not last long for you (:

Comment: I updated the answer with ideas. Might work or be a starting point for a research (: